# Executing object file using shell_exec() by passing string argument

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am executing object file `b` which is achieved from executing c++ program from php page in this way:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$temp=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));
//$temp = "one one two";
$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Extra/Modular2/b " . $temp);
echo $output;
?>
```

When I pass `$temp = "one one two";` then it gives result:

`Client : /home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Extra/Modular2/b filename @ar[0]=0;ar[1]=0@`

When I execute `./b "one one two"` in command line it gives me result:

```
technoworld@ubuntu:~/Videos/LinSocket/Extra/Modular2$ ./b "one one,wo"
Client : 

string is :one one,wo 

one one wo 

 @ar[0]=1;ar[1]=2@
```

so why while passing it from php file it gives wrong result?

And when I pass content of webpage as argument in `$temp` which is achieved from `$text = file_get_contents($url);  $temp=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));` then it shows nothing on browser?

Can some one  identify what is the problem here?

Comment: try to encode the space inside the param string

Comment: Print the command. You'll see it isn't the same that the one you're comparing against.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The documentation of `escapeshellarg` says it puts quotes around the entire string.

Comment: @Dheed: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Barmar: `escapeshellarg` as per above syntax work correctly for my another example. Even I am checking document and testing again!

Comment: Seeing the `@ar[0]=1ar[1]=2@` reminds me of something (:-P), perhaps add `sprintf(std::string(argc,"%s\n"), argv);` (iterator over argv, of course

Comment: @Karimkhan if I'm not wrong each space means a new parameter, but I don't know how it behave when you pass a string(maybe quote it)

Comment: @Dheed: You're right: each space === new param, but Barmar pointed out that, according to the docs, the entire string should be quoted by `escapeshellarg`

Comment: Is `./b` printing some of its output to `stderr`? I think `shell_exec()` only captures `stdout`, that's why you don't see `string is:`.

Comment: You're getting the input from an HTML page, so it _may_ contain new-lines, thousands of words, invalid markup and it _could_ very well not be utf-8 encoded data, or non-ascii chars. Perhaps `$text = "'" . str_replace("'", "'\"'\"'", $text) . "'";` wight work better (it's a firty fix taken from the man pages)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: You meant `$temp=escapeshellarg('strip_tags($text)');`

Comment: @Karimkhan: No, I suggested something like `escapeshellarg(strip_tags('"'.$text.'"'));` but deleted the comment because Barmar pointed out it wasn't relevant

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: `$text = "'" . str_replace("'", "'\"'\"'", $text) . "'";` does not help!

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, actually my object file gives me most occuring word. For my another object file I executed above code with `$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x " . $temp);` which takes data from `$text = file_get_contents($url);` and gives output `you:44 the:38 to:38 ` in browser. If you are willing to help me then I can give object files!

Comment: @Barmar: No, it does not print to `stderr`!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Can you please elaborate what you want to say?

Comment: If you `var_dump("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Extra/Modular2/b " . $temp)` you'll see that you don't have quotes around `"one one,wo"` as others have already pointed out.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: var_dump prints `string(9031) "/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Extra/Modular2/b'` and then entire content of page. No "one one,wo"

Comment: Let me guess: you haven't commented out `//$temp = "one one two";`, have you? Whatever, you claim that the same code works fine in command line—I was just pointing out that you are not running the *same* code.